# Tabela não exibe nome relativo a Chave-Estrangeira PHP Tabela

Tags: php, mysql, chave-estrangeira

Preciso fazer uma consulta na tabela e que retorne a **Data** na **primeira** coluna, Nome (FK) na segunda coluna, e demais dados dependentes da FK nas suas respectivas colunas. Já tentei as diversas formas de **INNER JOIN** e não consigo mostrar na tabela o nome do paciente, apenas seu código. Alguém me daria uma dica, ou o que tenho de alterar no código?

As minhas tabelas são:

Tabela........||     Campo
Agenda..... ||      Data,   Hora, Cod_Paciente, Faltou
Pacientes...||Codigo, Nome, Telefone, Cod_Convenio, telefone, celular

Ligadas por

agenda:.......       Cod_Paciente
Pacientes:...   Codigo

Eu já consigo montar a tabela com todos os horários porém não consigo exibir o nome do paciente dentro da coluna relativa. Já tentei o while de diversas formas.

Eis o codigo:

```
include("conexao.php");  

// Escolhendo apenas a data atual.  
$query = "select * from agenda WHERE Data BETWEEN ('$date') AND ('$date');";  
$resultado = mysql_query($query,$conexao) or die(mysql_error());  

//Fazendo o join na tabela pacientes  
$query2 = "SELECT
            p.codigo,
            nome,
            sexo,
            profissao,
            celular,
            observacoes,
            codigo_convenio,
            a.codigo_paciente, 
            hora, 
            faltou 
           FROM pacientes p 
           JOIN agenda a ON a.codigo_paciente = p.codigo 
           ORDER BY data,hora";

$resultado2=mysql_query($query2,$conexao) or die(mysql_error());  

// montar a tabela   

if(mysql_num_rows($resultado)>0)  
    print "<table border='3' ALIGN='center'><FONT FACE='Arial' SIZE='10' COLOR='black'>";  

print "<tr colspan='10' rowspan='10'><td id='celula0'>Hora</td><td id='celula1'>Paciente</td><td id='celula2'>Presente?</td><td id='celula3'>P.Saude</td><td id='celula4'>Tel</td><td id='celula2'>Histórico</td></tr>";  

while ($info2=mysql_fetch_array($resultado2))
{  
    while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($resultado))  
    {  
        print "<tr colspan='10' rowspan='10'><td id='celula0'>$info[hora]</td> <td id='celula1'>$info2[nome]</td><td id='celula2'>$info[faltou]</td><td id='celula3'>$info[codigo_paciente]</td><td id='celula4'>$info[codigo_paciente]</td><td id='celula4'>$info[codigo_paciente]</td></tr>";  
    }  
    print "</table>";  
}  
?>  
</body>  
</html>
```

[image: print da tela]

Comment: O codigo que você postou possui joins? Para fazer um é preciso saber as colunas e as tabelas do banco de dados envolvidas.

Comment: Conforme o @Juven_v mencionou, é necessário que você cite os campos da(s) tabela(s) para que possamos elaborar uma resposta. No código acima, o JOIN está comentado, mas provavelmente irá usá-lo, caso hajam outras tabelas (é o que imagino que aconteça).

Comment: @ThiagoBarros então eu já fiz a join e testei no mysql, a minha dificuldade é como eu vou coloca-la dentro do php para exibir o nome na coluna certa.

Comment: @CleudineyTheodoroBrandão você utiliza a coluna "nome" em alguma outra tabela que está fazendo join?